# How to restrict user to select cell sequentially in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing a problem regarding to select cell scenically.Means user can not click directly on 3rd row he should select 1st row, then 2nd row and the 3rd row. Is it is possible??

I try this code

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

But using this code I can not select any cell.I have a dynamic array from web service. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @Jecky How Can you share some code please..

Comment: just record the last index and unselect the row if its not the next index

Comment: I have different logic than that @Tj3n

Comment: @Jecky Share hear please.

Comment: I used to work with NSMutableArray for it, But I think your 's is better than me. So thank you for this @Muju

Comment: @Jecky Please share your code I can try your code..

Comment: @Tj3n Can you please share code how to do this.

Comment: @Muju Please check my answer and let me know is it correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the last `indexPath.row` to compare your current selected row. The code below forces user select row at order: user must select row 0 -> row 1 -> row 2.

```
NSIndexPath *_lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
NSMutableArray *_selectedIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([_selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        // Set the color for selected cell
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_lastIndexPath.row + 1 >= indexPath.row) {
        // Implement what you want
    } else {
        // You should show the introduction of order operation for user
        _lastIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
    if (![_selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) { // Check if array does not contain selecting cell, add this cell to array
        [_selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is _lastIndexPath is it last index store value.

Comment: Yes it stores the last NSIndexPath that user can select.

Comment: But where to declare this line  NSIndexPath *_lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

Comment: If _lastIndexPath.row = 0 (the first row), user cannot select the 2nd row. It is the main idea.

Comment: You should put it in `viewDidLoad` or when you created yourTableView (if you created yourTableView by coding).

Comment: can I change the cell colour in same way. Like All the selected cell are set to be green and unselect index are set to be white or red.

Comment: In that case you have to create a new NSMutableArray for store all row you selected. And in cellforRowAtIndexpath, check [array containsObject: indexPath] then set selected color.

Comment: Updated answer. But the next time you should do it by yourself, it is very simple logic for implement. Cheers.

Comment: Got one problem. When I click on 1st row and 2nd row it work proper. Then I click on third row it goes in else condition even I click on 2nd cell.

Comment: Happen all row below 2nd row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131016/discussion-between-nynohu-and-muju).

Comment: _lastIndexPath.row + 1 is not incrementing so value is mismatch. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Take `NSMutableArray` like

```
NSMutableArray *arr_selected_indexs = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

into `tableview`'s `cellforRowAtIndexpath` method

check

```
if indexPath == 0
{
cell.userInteractionenabled = YES;
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
 }else if [arr containsObject : indexPath.row]
{

cell.userInteractionenabled = YES;
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}else
{
 cell.userInteractionenabled = NO;
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Now into `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
[arr addObject: indexPath.row +1 ];
[self.tableView reloaddata];
```

Comment: can I change the cell colour in same way. Like All the selected cell are set to be green and unselect index are set to be white or red.

Comment: @Muju I updated my code as per you want. Please check it

Comment: Please see the nynohu answer  
_lastIndexPath.row + 1 is not incrementing . Please help.

Comment: @Muju You will try my answer for all indexes. though I will try above answer and let you know about it

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

for particular row of selection and ignore the row selection simply by

```
return NO;
```